# DataSet visualizer stays empty

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2010, debugging, dataset

I have a old .Net 2.0 Webservice, which I work with in a .Net3.5 WPF app. The service is sending me DataSet as byte Arrays (byte[]) which works. I get the data on the client side, and I'm able to convert it back to a dataset with no problems.

But when I want to see the received dataset on client side in the dataset visualizer of VS2010, it shows me an empty dataset with no tables and no rows/columns.

The weird part is now that this dataset isn't empty. I can access dataset.Tables[0] or .Rows[0][0] which gives me a datatable or with row the first cell. it all works. but when ever I'm trying to see the dataset or datatable in visualizer it stays empty.

I tried to use the WriteXml and ReadXml methods to transfer the data between service and client, but this doesn't help either.

I'm thinking I missed something quite basics, but I just can't find it so far.

Many thanks to every suggestion I can get here!

edit:
Problem doesn't appear with .Net 4.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this weird DataSet visualizer problem by setting my project in VS2010 to .Net 4.0 and then back again to .Net 3.5. After that it doesn't appear anymore.